# Dockerfile not running my mock api and reactjs app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, devops

Good Morning. I am trying to run the docker file to start my mock api and my UI.
When I run those inside individual terminals, I am able to see the UI up and running. But when I run those inside a docker container the API doesn't start for some reasons.

Can you help me with this?

```
# My Docker file.

FROM node:11


# Set working directory for API
RUN mkdir /usr/src/api
WORKDIR /usr/src/api

COPY ./YYY/. /usr/src/api/.

RUN npm install

RUN npm start &

# set working directory for UI
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/

COPY ./ZZZ/. /usr/src/app/.

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

EXPOSE 3000

RUN npm install 

RUN npm start
```

Thanks,
Ranjith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `npm start` starts a web server that only listens on the loopback interface of the container. To fix this, in `package.json`, under start, add `—host 0.0.0.0`. This will allow you to access the app in your browser using the container ip.